# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/operation/ReadOperation

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm working on a DB project and this class instantiation code below seems to be failing. I can't seem to figure out why. I've made sure to run mongod and start MongoDB. Does anyone have any tips on how to resolve this?

```
public DatabaseInterface() {
        this.mongoClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017); ## This line
        this.database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbmsProjectDB");
        this.gson = new Gson();
    }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/operation/ReadOperation
    at backend.DatabaseInterface.<init>(DatabaseInterface.java:54)
    at backend.main.main(main.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.operation.ReadOperation
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Which version of `MongoDb` driver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `MongoClients.create(uri)` instead

```java
String uri = "mongodb://localhost";
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri);
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbmsProjectDB");
```

Answer (score 0):

The message tells you that he is not able to find the class `com.mongodb.operation.ReadOperation`. This means that this class is no longer available in this location.

Upgrade the version of your MongoDb `Java Driver` to the `4.X.X` versions.
Beginning from those versions, the path of the `ReadOperation` class has changed to another location : `com.mongodb.internal.operation.ReadOperation`